# java -jar command line additional input

Tags: java, jar

i want to do the following?

```
java -jar File.jar username password
```

Where the fields "username" and "password"  will be passed by the user while executing the java -jar File.jar command.

how to do that?

Comment: Which four fields? It's not clear what you're asking. (There are *three* values after the jar file name - and they're passed to `main` just like normal...)

Comment: modified the question, want to pass the username and the password along with java -jar file.jar command.

Comment: Now there are only 2 values passed and they will be `args[0]` and `args[1]` in your `public static void main(String[] args)` method

Comment: i just want to know how to pass additional fields.

Comment: @noone : I understand that part but I want to pass the information from the command line along with java -jar file.jar command

Comment: @user2602860: It's really unclear what you don't understand - you use the command you've written, and in your `main` method you'll get the values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your File.jar you have an entry point somewhere in the form of `public static void main(String[] args)`.

When you execute the following command `java -jar File.jar username password` you can catch the input parameters like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String username = args[0];
    String password = args[1];

    ...
}
```

Comment: how is that possible?

Comment: This is just how the commandline and the `java` command work. You don't have to do anything else.